# How do I change the Admin password on a Ubee DVW3201B?

Tags: networking

I must admit that I feel rather foolish having to ask this.

I recently switched ISPs, and the new one gave us a Ubee DVW3201B as our home gateway.  I want to change the Administrator username/password from the defaults, but I've been having some difficulty.

Every time, after I save the new username and password, I'm prompted to re-authenticate to the administration interface.  It fails no matter what I try.  I've tried using:

- New username / New password
- Default username / New password
- Default username / Default password

None of the above works.  This has happened twice now, with my only recourse after failure being to do a reset to factory defaults (press and hold the hard reset button for 10 seconds).

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Did you try only changing one at a time?

Comment: Not yet, though the thought had occurred to me.  Right now I'm trying to FTFM.  And yes, that first letter was meant to be an "F".  As in "Find"!

Comment: Confirmed that changing the password alone will work.  Don't want to test the username change anymore, because I really don't want to have to do another reset.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the password by itself (not changing the username in the same operation) seems to have worked.  I haven't tested if changing the username alone works at all, because by the point I figured this much out I didn't really feel like doing another router reset if it didn't work.